# How to get coordinates of a particular region in android?

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-canvas

I am making a game with a shooter such that when use click it should move left or right but it is made on canvas and onclick listeners didn't work on it  so someone told me to get coordinates of canvas and use onclick listeners on it but he don't tell me how to do it
My Code

```
package --------;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Cannon {
    float x = -1; // Cannon's center (x,y)
    float y = -1;
    float stepX = 40;
    int lowerX, lowerY, upperX, upperY;
    private Paint paint;

    private Context mContext;

    // Constructor
    public Cannon(int color, Context c) {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(color);

        mContext = c;

    }

    public void setBounds(int lx, int ly, int ux, int uy) {
        lowerX = lx;
        lowerY = ly;
        upperX = ux;
        upperY = uy;

        x = ux/2;
        y = uy;
    }

    public void moveLeft() {

        if (x - 30 > 0) {
            x -= stepX;
        }
    }

    public void moveRight() {

        if (x + 30 < upperX) {
            x += stepX;
        }
    }

    public float getPosition() {
        return x;
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawLine(x, y -120, x, y, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(x - 90, y - 40, x + 90, y, paint);


    }
}
```

how to use onclick listeners  for this rectangle by getting its coordinates to do move left function

Answer (score 0):

You already have a method `getPosition`, but it only returns the `x` position.. Create one that returns `x` and one that returns `y`, for example:

```
public float getCannonX(){
    return x;
}

public float getCannonY(){
    return y;
}
```

Then in your `Activity` you can set an `onClickListener` on your cannon object and access the methods above.

Or you can set an `onClickListener` on your canvas and use the above methods to check if the cannon coordinates was selected.

You should factor in the size of the cannon object as well

Comment: How to use onClickListener on Cannon Object .... oR how to use onClickListener on a Canvas Objects .........

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you are asking? Just set an `onClickListener` to your Cannon object in your `Activity`

Comment: I used addView(Object); on it and than a onclicklistener as you said although thank you!!